# Set Dialog theme to parent Theme in Android

Tags: android

I'm creating a custom Holo theme in which I want to customize Dialog look and feel.
What is the attribute for Dialog?

```
<style name="MyHolo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
   <item name="*********">@style/MyDialogStyle</item>
....
</style>

<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:textColor">#223523</item>
...
</style>
```

and in Manifest:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/MyHolo">
```

ps where can I find all the attributes? I dont see a single place for all of them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check this out! https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light" parent="Theme.Light">
        <item name="colorForeground">@android:color/bright_foreground_holo_light</item>
        <item name="colorForegroundInverse">@android:color/bright_foreground_inverse_holo_light</item>
        <item name="colorBackground">@android:color/background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="colorBackgroundCacheHint">@android:drawable/background_cache_hint_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="disabledAlpha">0.5</item>
    <item name="backgroundDimAmount">0.6</item>

    <item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    <item name="colorFocusedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorMultiSelectHighlight">@color/holo_green_light</item>
    <item name="colorActivatedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_dark</item>

    <!-- Text styles -->
    <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Inverse</item>

    <item name="textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorTertiary">@android:color/tertiary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorTertiaryInverse">@android:color/tertiary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_disable_only_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_disable_only_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_nodisable_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_nodisable_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_nodisable_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_nodisable_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorHint">@android:color/hint_foreground_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorHintInverse">@android:color/hint_foreground_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorSearchUrl">@android:color/search_url_text_holo</item>
    <item name="textColorHighlight">@android:color/highlighted_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorHighlightInverse">@android:color/highlighted_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorLink">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="textColorLinkInverse">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/primary_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceLarge">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceMedium">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Small</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargeInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Large.Inverse</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceMediumInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Medium.Inverse</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Small.Inverse</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultTitle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.SearchResult.Title</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Widget.Button</item>

    <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="editTextBackground">@android:drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="candidatesTextStyleSpans">@android:string/candidates_style</item>

    <item name="textCheckMark">@android:drawable/indicator_check_mark_light</item>
    <item name="textCheckMarkInverse">@android:drawable/indicator_check_mark_dark</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>

    <!-- Button styles -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button</item>

    <item name="buttonStyleSmall">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small</item>
    <item name="buttonStyleInset">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Inset</item>

    <item name="buttonStyleToggle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Toggle</item>
    <item name="switchStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch</item>

    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@android:drawable/item_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@android:drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>

    <!-- List attributes -->
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeight">64dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">48dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightLarge">80dip</item>
    <item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceListItemSmall">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">8dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">8dip</item>

    <!-- @hide -->
    <item name="searchResultListItemHeight">58dip</item>
    <item name="listDivider">@drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
    <item name="listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator</item>   

    <item name="listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@android:drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>
    <item name="listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@android:drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>

    <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@android:drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>

    <item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@android:drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>

    <item name="expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft">40dip</item>
    <item name="expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft">?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft</item>

    <item name="expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft">3dip</item>
    <item name="expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight">0dip</item>
    <item name="expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorLeft">?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft</item>
    <item name="expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorRight">?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight</item>

    <item name="listDividerAlertDialog">@android:drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>

    <!-- Gallery attributes -->
    <item name="galleryItemBackground">@android:drawable/gallery_item_background</item>

    <!-- Window attributes -->
    <item name="windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:drawable/ab_solid_shadow_holo</item>
    <item name="windowShowWallpaper">false</item>
    <item name="windowTitleStyle">@android:style/WindowTitle.Holo</item>
    <item name="windowTitleSize">25dip</item>
    <item name="windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@android:style/WindowTitleBackground.Holo</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Holo.Activity</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustUnspecified</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>

    <!-- Dialog attributes -->
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@android:style/AlertDialog.Holo.Light</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleIconsDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title_icons_holo</item>
    <item name="dialogCustomTitleDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_custom_title_holo</item>
    <item name="dialogTitleDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title_holo</item>
    <item name="alertDialogCenterButtons">false</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="alertDialogIcon">@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert_holo_light</item>

    <item name="toastFrameBackground">@android:drawable/toast_frame_holo</item>

    <!-- Panel attributes -->
    <item name="panelBackground">@android:drawable/menu_hardkey_panel_holo_light</item>
    <item name="panelFullBackground">@android:drawable/menu_background_fill_parent_width</item>
    <!-- These three attributes do not seems to be used by the framework. Declared public though -->
    <item name="panelColorBackground">#000</item>
    <item name="panelColorForeground">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="panelTextAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearance</item>

    <item name="panelMenuIsCompact">true</item>
    <item name="panelMenuListWidth">250dip</item>
    <item name="panelMenuListTheme">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.CompactMenu</item>

    <!-- Scrollbar attributes -->
    <item name="scrollbarFadeDuration">250</item>
    <item name="scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">300</item>
    <item name="scrollbarSize">10dip</item>
    <item name="scrollbarThumbHorizontal">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="scrollbarTrackHorizontal">@null</item>
    <item name="scrollbarTrackVertical">@null</item>

    <!-- Text selection handle attributes -->
    <item name="textSelectHandleLeft">@android:drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
    <item name="textSelectHandleRight">@android:drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
    <item name="textSelectHandle">@android:drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
    <item name="textSelectHandleWindowStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextSelectHandle</item>
    <item name="textSuggestionsWindowStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextSuggestionsPopupWindow</item>
    <item name="textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/text_cursor_holo_light</item>

    <!-- Widget styles -->
    <item name="absListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.AbsListView</item>
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView</item>
    <item name="checkboxStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText</item>
    <item name="expandableListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ExpandableListView</item>
    <item name="expandableListViewWhiteStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ExpandableListView.White</item>
    <item name="galleryStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Gallery</item>
    <item name="gestureOverlayViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.GestureOverlayView</item>
    <item name="gridViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.GridView</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton</item>
    <item name="imageWellStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageWell</item>
    <item name="listViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView</item>
    <item name="listViewWhiteStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.White</item>
    <item name="popupWindowStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleSmall">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleSmallTitle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small.Title</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleLarge">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleInverse">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Inverse</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleSmallInverse">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyleLargeInverse">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse</item>
    <item name="seekBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.SeekBar</item>
    <item name="ratingBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar</item>
    <item name="ratingBarStyleIndicator">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Indicator</item>
    <item name="ratingBarStyleSmall">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Small</item>
    <item name="radioButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton</item>
    <item name="scrollViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ScrollView</item>
    <item name="horizontalScrollViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.HorizontalScrollView</item>
    <item name="spinnerStyle">?android:attr/dropDownSpinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownSpinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown</item>
    <item name="starStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Star</item>
    <item name="tabWidgetStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TabWidget</item>
    <item name="textViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView</item>
    <item name="errorMessageBackground">@android:drawable/popup_inline_error_holo_light</item>
    <item name="errorMessageAboveBackground">@android:drawable/popup_inline_error_above_holo_light</item>
    <item name="webTextViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.WebTextView</item>
    <item name="webViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.WebView</item>
    <item name="dropDownItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="dropDownHintAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.DropDownHint</item>
    <item name="keyboardViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.KeyboardView</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleWindowSmall">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadge.WindowSmall</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleWindowMedium">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadge.WindowMedium</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleWindowLarge">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadge.WindowLarge</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleSmallWindowSmall">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowSmall</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleSmallWindowMedium">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowMedium</item>
    <item name="quickContactBadgeStyleSmallWindowLarge">@android:style/Widget.Holo.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge</item>
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="stackViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.StackView</item>
    <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActivityChooserView</item>

    <!-- Preference styles -->
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.PreferenceScreen</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment.Holo</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.Category</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo</item>
    <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.Information</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.CheckBoxPreference</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.SwitchPreference</item>
    <item name="yesNoPreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.DialogPreference.YesNoPreference</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.DialogPreference</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference</item>
    <item name="ringtonePreferenceStyle">@android:style/Preference.Holo.RingtonePreference</item>
    <item name="preferenceLayoutChild">@android:layout/preference_child_holo</item>
    <item name="detailsElementBackground">@android:drawable/panel_bg_holo_light</item>

    <!-- Search widget styles -->
    <item name="searchWidgetCorpusItemBackground">@android:color/search_widget_corpus_item_background</item>

    <!-- Action bar styles -->
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@android:drawable/cab_background_top_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@android:drawable/cab_background_bottom_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_default_height</item>
    <item name="actionModePopupWindowStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@null</item>

    <item name="actionModeCutDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_cut_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeCopyDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModePasteDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_paste_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_selectall_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeFindDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_find_holo_light</item>
    <item name="actionModeWebSearchDrawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_search_holo_light</item>

    <item name="dividerVertical">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    <item name="dividerHorizontal">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="segmentedButtonStyle">@android:style/Holo.Light.SegmentedButton</item>

    <!-- SearchView attributes -->
    <item name="searchDropdownBackground">@android:drawable/search_dropdown_light</item>

    <item name="searchDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Holo.Light.SearchBar</item>

    <!-- NumberPicker attributes and styles-->
    <item name="numberPickerUpButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton.NumberPickerUpButton</item>
    <item name="numberPickerDownButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton.NumberPickerDownButton</item>
    <item name="numberPickerInputTextStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText.NumberPickerInputText</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>

    <!-- CalendarView style-->
    <item name="calendarViewStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.CalendarView</item>

    <!-- TimePicker style -->
    <item name="timePickerStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.TimePicker</item>

    <!-- DatePicker style -->
    <item name="datePickerStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.Light.DatePicker</item>

    <item name="fastScrollThumbDrawable">@android:drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft">@android:drawable/fastscroll_label_left_holo_light</item>
    <item name="fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@android:drawable/fastscroll_label_right_holo_light</item>
    <item name="fastScrollTrackDrawable">@android:drawable/fastscroll_track_holo_light</item>
    <item name="fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Cannot use Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.Alert as parent of my dialog theme (alertDialogTheme)

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes_holo.xml